# Android Emulator not starting up: "Android Emulator closed because of an internal error:..."

Tags: android, arm, emulation

I am trying to start up an Android Emulator via Android Studio, but it is dying with:

```
 Android Emulator closed because of an internal error:
 emuglConfig_init: blacklisted=0 has_guest_renderer=0            mode:swiftshader_indirect,option: 
 (null) … Swiftshader selected, enabling Vulkan."
```

I have tried these things so far (based on recommendations I found on Stackoverflow and elsewhere):

- updated the "SDK Tools" via Android Studio, where updates were available and cleared the cache; restarted Android Studio.
- changed emulator option: "Graphics:" to "Software GLES 1.1"
- checked the space I have on Mac:
  Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
  /dev/disk1s5s1   500G    15G    48G    25%  553788 4881899092    0%   /, so there is 48GB free on '/' directory
  and the emulator "size on disk" is 1.4GB so it seems there is adequate space.
- tried a cold boot of the emulator but fails just the same as when I "Run app" via Android Studio.

These are the emulator particulars:

- Pixel 5 API 30
- 1080x2340: 440 dpi
- Android 11.0
- CPU: ARM64

Previously, I was using x86 based emulators (versus ARM now) and they seemed to pop up just fine. (Aiming for ARM as the target this time since I want to run on a Google Pixel phone). Not sure what to make of this.  Anyway, stuck currently.  If anyone has any ideas on how I might be able to get past this issue, pls let me know.  **Any** recommendations appreciated.

Comment: Testing starting up emulator from command line as: %emulator -avd Pixel_5_API_30 -qemu -machine virt.   This momentarily brings up an emulator with a black screen, but it. quickly dies with a new error: "ERROR   | eglMakeCurrent failed in binding subwindow!".  Anyone familiar with what this error means and how. I can address it pls let me know.

Comment: I was able to get past the "eglMakeCurrent failed in binding subwindow!" error by setting the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable.  Also I dropped down 2 API's to 29, now the emulator appears, saying set for COLD BOOT, however, the screen stays black and I get these messages: ERROR   | detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'. No response for 124998 ms
ERROR   | detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU0 thread'. No response for 124998 ms.  I am setting -selinux permissive.  Not sure if this is correct?  If anyone recognizes this error and what may trigger it pls let me know.  Thanks.